# Minecraft server suddenly not accessible via external ISP IP address after working previously

Tags: port-forwarding, minecraft

I've recently have been hosting a server with some friends on Minecraft. It's been working for a few days, but today when I turned it on, the server wouldn't allow anyone to connect.

I made sure to port forward, as you can see here:

[image: Port forwarding setup.]

Whenever I try connecting from an external IP, as well as my friends testing this, we just get this error:

[image: Connection error screenshot.]

I made sure  that the internal IP is correct, and I'm able to connect through localhost.

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Has your ISP blocked you or are.you (now) behind Carrier Grade NAT? Does the server respond on your LAN?

Comment: I tested the server using localhost, and the server seems to work. I'm not entirely sure how to test whether or not my ISP blocked me or if I'm behind CGN, but the webpage https://canyouseeme.org says that my ISP is not blocking 25565, if that helps.

Comment: Can you connect to it on 192.168.1.168  from your LAN?  Also, try STOPPING the server and rerun the tests from canoyouseeme.org

Comment: I am able to connect to the server on 192.168.1.168 through my lan, and when I stopped the server and ran tests from https://canyouseeme.org the port was closed. The port only shows that it is open when I start the server.

Comment: Well that means that it is highly unlikely your ISP is blocking you, and also that the router is set up correctly.  It also means that (at some level) your Minecraft server is talking to the wider internet.

Comment: So is there any solution to this problem? Like you said, it's reaching the internet in some form, so what could be causing it, and can I fix it?